# How to implement scrolling on component with HTML elements that are stacked on each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm working on an Angular app that aims to offer some basic layer operations: adding and position layers, scaling, rotating, etc.

In the following image for example 3 layers have been added, the background and two layers that have transparency, they have been positioned using a div with `position: absolute`

[image]

As you can see when any of the layers are bigger than the available height or width, scrollbars are being produced.

I need those scrollbars (both vertical an horizontal) in the component with the green border. In a way that any image size will be shown inside the green component (divLayers), including small images that are position really wide or at the bottom.

I have checked many tutorials about this, but all of them use items that are position relative inside the component that has the scrolls.

I found something close to what I need but dont understand how to apply it.
https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3409-using-position-absolute-inside-a-scrolling-overflow-container.htm

[image]

Here are the relevant HTML and CSS files

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="divMain">
    <app-tool-bar class="divToolBar"></app-tool-bar>
    <app-layer-presenter class="divLayerPresenter"></app-layer-presenter >
</div>
```

**layer-presenter.html**

```html
<div class="divLayers">
    <div *ngFor="let il of getLayers()">
        <img class="divFloatLayer" 
            [src]="il.img_src" 
            [style.left]="il.getLeftPx()"
            [style.top]="il.getTopPx()"
            [style.z-index]="il.getZindex()"
            [style.transform]="il.getTransform()"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<app-layer-list class="divLayerList"></app-layer-list>
```

**layer-presenter.css**

```css
.divLayers {
  width: 95%;
  flex-basis: 95%;
  border: 3px solid green; /*debug */
} 

.divLayerList {
  flex :1 ;
  border: 3px solid blue; /*debug */
}

.divFloatLayer {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: left top ;
    /*border: solid 1px red;  -- remove to debug */ 
}
```

**app.component.css**

```css
:host {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0; 
  border: solid 3px yellow; /*debug */
}

.divMain {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid; /*debug */
}

.divToolBar {
    border: 3px solid red; /*debug */
}

.divLayerPresenter {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 3px solid darkgrey; /*debug */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing another search I came along this article that implements a custom scrollbar in Angular
https://medium.com/its-tinkoff/custom-scrollbar-in-angular-93e23d47bf62

The source code for that article is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrollbar-component-directive

[image]

Including the scrollbar component into my project has solved the problem

That solution requires installing the following npm-packages

```
"@ng-web-apis/common": "^1.9.0",
"@ng-web-apis/resize-observer": "^1.0.3",
"@tinkoff/ng-event-plugins": "^2.2.0",
```

Adding the following to `app.module.ts`

```js
import { ScrollbarModule } from './shared/components/scrollbar/scrollbar.module';
import { NG_EVENT_PLUGINS } from '@tinkoff/ng-event-plugins';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ....
    ScrollbarModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NG_EVENT_PLUGINS
  ],
})
```

Wrapping the layers into the custom scroll bar in **layer-presenter.component.html**

```html
<scrollbar class="divLayers">
    <div *ngFor="let il of getLayers()">
        <img class="divFloatLayer" 
            [src]="il.img_src" 
            [style.left]="il.getLeftPx()"
            [style.top]="il.getTopPx()"
            [style.z-index]="il.getZindex()"
            [style.transform]="il.getTransform()"
        />
    </div>
</scrollbar>
<app-layer-list class="divLayerList"></app-layer-list>
```

Now the scrollbars are appearing when needed only in the layer-presenter component and not in the main viewport of the browser

[image]